# Custom Outlook Forms on Blackberry

Tags: outlook, blackberry, bes

I've been asked to create some custom forms in Outlook - does anybody know of a plugin or add on for either Blackberry devices or the BES that will enable the forms to be viewed on Blackberry devices?

Comment: Anyone at all ?

Answer (score 1):

A good solution for you would be our inForm product.  It comes with a free form editor and allows you to create custom forms for the BlackBerry.  Users can then complete the forms and email the results.  You can see this at skysoftsystems.com.

Thanks.

Comment: As much as I hate commercial plugging on SF, this seems to be pretty much the only thing resembling an answer.